# Fish Shell: multiple commands on one line, when some of them run in background

Tags: fish

Fish Shell:

```
git add --all; git commit -m "fix";  (git push psnano master &  git push psnanoserv master)
```

The above doesn't work. This may be crazy, but am trying to do this in one line:

Do these commands in order:

```
git add --all
git commit -m "fix"
```

And when they complete, do these commands in parallel:

```
git push psnano master
git push psnanoserv master
```

Doc isn't clear about this. Maybe it cannot be done in FISH?

Answer (score 9):

> This may be crazy, but am trying to do this in one line

There's no technical reason to do it in one line, and I'd recommend not always trying to fit everything into one line.

Regardless, if you want:

```
git add --all; git commit -m "fix"; git push psnano master & git push psnanoserv master
```

The `()` denote subshells in POSIX shells and aren't needed in this case.

Fish doesn't support that syntax (`()` denotes command substitutions) and doesn't quite have subshells (there are `begin; end` blocks, but they're not as isolated as subshells are), so the `()` simply need to be removed.

The `;` can be replaced by newlines, so

```
git add --all
git commit -m "fix"
git push psnano master &
git push psnanoserv master
```

means the exact same thing.

Comment: for bonus points, what if i want to do the pushes only conditionally, only if the `git commit` suceeds? you cannot put an `and` after an `&`...

Comment: Just use `if git commit` - you can't use two `and` because that would predicate the second push on the first, which makes no sense considering it's backgrounded.

Comment: *or* in that case actually do use `begin` and `end` - `git commit -m "fix"; and begin git push psnano master & git push psnanoserv master; end`